# URL Redirect through .Htaccess doesn't work in Php Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I want to that when I enter localhost/projectname/index.html it will redirect to

```
http://localhost/service/welcome/index
```

For this I write that in .htaccess but it doesn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

Redirect /index.html http://localhost/service/welcome/index
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In codeigniter there is **no files are calling** in URL. All what Codeigniter do is use ***MVC Structure*** to render view.

As well as if you access anything on root folder(index.html or index.php) it will redirect to application folder. Then default controller is Trigger out.

cz in root there is file call `index.php`, there you can see

```
$application_folder = 'application';
$system_path = 'system';
```

And you can take look at this

1. routes - `config/routes.php`
2. controller - `controller/`
3. model - `model/`
4. view - `view/`

and we use `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` in URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

if you want to add `.html` or `.php` end of URL

in `config/config.php`

```
/*

  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  | URL suffix

  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  |

  | This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.

  | For more information please see the user guide:

  |

  | http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

 */
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Comment: There are no redirect options in it?

Comment: Then how can I redirect or trigger that?

Comment: redirect for what ?? we use .htaccess to remove index.php in URL

Comment: I want when I write localhost/projectname/index.html in url it goes to home controller and index action

Comment: how it make sure that this url request go to home controller and index action

Comment: if u define in routes it will go to your controller and if there is no function call its automatically call `index()`

Comment: meanz default controller and default action

Comment: ya. you have to define default contoller in `config/routes.php`